# O que são e para que servem as "conversas marcadas" no chat?

Tags: suporte, chat

Na página de [*informações gerais do "Estouro de Pilha"*](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/11910/estouro-de-pilha) existe uma aba **conversations** com algumas conversas que foram marcadas pelos usuários [Delfino](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/8039/delfino) e [bfavaretto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/74/bfavaretto):

[image: bookmarked conversations]

A minha primeira pergunta é: O que são essas conversas?

Se elas estão em uma aba isolada provavelmente devem ter uma importância maior ou servem como histórico para algo já discutido, não entendi muito bem. Então, minha outra pergunta é: Para que servem essas conversas?

Comment: Nunca tinha notado isso. Kkkk